# El enrutamiento selectivo me bloquea la conexión

Tags: linux, debian, redes

Tengo un equipo Debian y le he puesto una tarjeta de red Wifi, aparte de la tarjeta por cable (eth0) que ya tenía, para utilizarla para transferir archivos hacia una IP pública. Primero cree una ruta estática de la siguiente forma y me funcionaba:

```
ip route add <red ip pública>/24 via 192.168.200.1 dev wlan0
```

Después la eliminé para intentar lo mismo pero con enrutamiento selectivo. Cree una regla de iptables para marcar los paquetes a transferir con:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -t mangle -p tcp --dport 22 -d <ip pública> -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

Cree una nueva tabla de enrutamiento:

```
echo 201 wifi >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Hago que los paquetes marcados utilizen la nueva tabla:

```
ip rule add fwmark 1 table wifi
```

Y creo la regla de enrutamiento en la tabla:

```
ip route add <red ip pública>/24 via 192.168.200.1 dev wlan0 table wifi
```

Tras todo esto pruebo a transferir un archivo pero se me queda bloqueado. Haciendo un tcpdump para filtrar el tráfico del puerto 22 en el primer caso tenia conexiones de la siguiente forma:

```
IP 192.168.200.18.58582 > "<ip pública>".staticip.rima-tde.net.22
IP "<ip pública>".staticip.rima-tde.net.22 > 192.168.200.18.58582
```

La ip de origen es la de mi interfaz Wifi y obtengo respuesta de la IP pública. Sin embargo, con el enrutamiento selectivo tengo:

```
IP 10.80.4.2.34882 > "<ip pública>".staticip.rima-tde.net.22
```

Salgo con la IP de mi interfaz eth0 y no obtengo respuesta.

La ruta estática en la tabla wifi es igual que la que cree originalmente por lo que entiendo que debe de funcionar de la misma forma, suponiendo que los paquetes estén siendo bien marcados. Sin marcar los paquetes me funciona la transferencia por la eth0 pero necesito hacerlo por la wlan0.

Me gustaría saber que estoy haciendo mal. Gracias de antemano.